# php - create assciative array while loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, while-loop, associative-array

I am trying to create 2 new arrays out of one existing array ($array), using the following "foreach" loop. However I am not sure it is correct:

```
        $emails = array();
        $numbers = array();
        while($array){
            $entry = $array['entry1'];
            $number = number($entry);
            if(isset($number) && (strlen($number) > 9)){
                $numbers[] = array('entry1' => $entry, 'number' => $number);
            }
            else{
                $email = email($entry);
                $emails[] = array('entry1' => $entry, 'email' => $email);
            }
        }
```

should the internal arrays have `[]`?
do I even need to start the arrays outside of the while loop? or skip it?
is it better to use a foreach loop?

Update:

Okay, here is the original array: It is extracted from a mysql query, of sets of two numbers:

`{('uid1','uid2'),('uid1','uid5'),('uid9','uid93'),....)`
There might be other data in each row, but these are the only two data points that really matter.

What I am trying to do is for a specific user ($entry), create two separate arrays: of all the users that have numbers (that's a function we have), and all the rest - of their emails.
So the outcome will be 2 new arrays which will look like this:
for a specific `uid79887`:

`numbers array: {('uid8','xxx-xxxx-xxx'),('uid34','yyy-yyyy-yyy'),('uid654','vvv-vvvv-vvv')}`

`emails array: {('uid4','mmm@mmm.com'),('uid1','lll@lll.com'),('uid55554','ppp@ppp.com')}`

Comment: what do you want to happen in making the array?

Comment: Could you post a `var_dump` of your original array, and how do you want the new arrays to look like?

Comment: You definitively shouldn't use an array-structure which requires you to use keys like "entry1", "entry2" etc. An array is either a list (with numbers as keys such as 0, 1, 2, 3...) or associative where the keys are names of elements (for example 'name', 'url', 'email' or whatever).

Comment: This will be an infinite while loop.

Answer (score 3):

Few things first:

- It's good practice to initialize your variables, just do it (it has many positives).
- What kind of test is `while($array)`? You should use `foreach( $array as $entry)` or `while( count( $array))` if you're removing items from array.
- Why are you testing `isset( $number)` when it's always set? It's initialized variable. You're probably checking `null`, so use `!is_null()` or `($number !== null)`. Even if it works it's misleading.

I **guess** your code should look like this:

```
$emails = array();
$numbers = array();
foreach( $array as $entry){
    $entry = isset( $entry['entry1']) ? $entry['entry1'] : null;
    $number = number( $entry);
    if( strlen($number) > 9 ){ // If $number is empty it will have strlen < 1 .)
       $numbers[] = array('entry1' => $entry, 'number' => $number);
    } else {
       $emails[] = array('entry1' => $entry, 'email' => email( $entry));
    }
}
```

Comment: well, we have a pretty similar answer ^^

Comment: good call about the"foreach", that's wht I had there first, donno why I changed it. 
secondly, 'number' is NOT always set. this is exactly what I am checking - if number is set I want to take this entry and include it in one array. if not - I want to take this entry and include it in the other array.

Comment: @LucyWeatherford `$number = function_call();` even if it doesn't return anything `var_dump($number)` will show `null` not `unset` or something like that. Anyway, what's not working on provided code?

Comment: how do I know whether $entry is $array['entry']?

Comment: did you skip that line on purpose? is it not necessary? thanks!

Comment: sorry but something is still not working: this is what I am getting on `var_dump`: `array(0) { } array(0) { }` any ideas?

Comment: @LucyWeatherford `var_dump( $what?)` but anyway I've update answer, added `entry = ...`...

Comment: `var_dump($numbers);` and `var_dump($emails);` also, you must mean `$entry = isset( $array['entry1']) ? $array['entry1'] : null;` and not what you wrote right? also, can you explain why is this necessary? thanks

Comment: @LucyWeatherford please add `var_export($array)` to your question

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505360/mysql-extracting-array-in-php) I wrote up my entire code

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are trying to acheive:

```
$emails = $numbers = Array();
foreach($array as $item) {
  $e = $item['entry1'];
  $number = number($e);
  if(strlen($number) > 9) {
    $numbers[] = Array('entry1' => $e, 'number' => $number);
  }
  else {
    $email = email($entry);
    $emails[] = Array('entry1' => $e, 'email' => $email);
  }
}
```

in your code, while($array) do not loop on the array, it loop until $array == false
as $array do not change in your loop it will either never enter or the loop, or never exit
generally, using a foreach loop produce code easier to understand

Comment: do you mean `$item['entry1'];`? also, $array is extracted from a mysql query, any ideas what I should add/change to make it from a resource ID into an array here? thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by "extracted from a mysql query" can you show the line where $array is assigned a value? or the output of var_dump($array);

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this isn't some kind of homework assignment, why don't you do it this way:

```
$emails = array();
$numbers = array();

foreach( $array as $entry )
{
    $number = number($entry);
    if( $number && strlen($number) > 9 )
    {
        array_push($numbers, array('entry1' => $entry, 'number' => $number));
    }
    else
    {
        array_push($emails, array('entry1' => $entry, 'email' => email($entry)));
    }
}
```

It is better to use built in functions that trying to roll your own.  The `foreach()` function works very well.