# Mysql extracting array in Php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

What is the problem with my mysql array extraction below:

```
        $mysql_array = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE uid1='$uid1'"); 
        $array = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_array)){
            $array[] = $row;
        }

        $array = array_unique($array);
        $array = array_reverse($array);
        $emails = array();
        $numbers = array();

        foreach($array as $row){
            $uid2 = $row['uid2'];
            $number = number($uid2);
            if(strlen($number) > 9){
                $numbers[] = array('uid2' => $uid2, 'number' => $number);
            }
            else{
                $email = email($uid2);
                $emails[] = array('uid2' => $uid2, 'email' => $email);
            }
        }
        $numbers = array_unique($numbers);
        $emails = array_unique($emails);            
        var_dump($numbers);
        var_dump($emails);
```

There must be something I need to do to convert the "Resource" from mysql into an array.
There must be a problem with the above code. 
This is what I am getting on the `var_dump`s: `array(0) { }` 
and `array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["uid2"]=> NULL ["email"]=> NULL } }`

Comment: What the purpose of this code?
`$number = number($yfbid);if(strlen($number) > 9){` , What?

Comment: sensible variable names would help a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php - create assciative array while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491091/php-create-assciative-array-while-loop)

Comment: what are you expecting to accomplish? I see several issues but I'm not even sure where to begin.

Comment: no it is not a possible duplicate, there the question was about the loop, now that that is covered, the question is about extracting the array from mysql. regarding the variables - you are right i had some of them wrong when i copied the code, now it's editted

Comment: what do the number() and email() functions do?

Comment: they extract respectively they user's number and email from the database.

Comment: What's that for a question? Is it not ok to downvote beginners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table1 WHERE uid1 = '{$uid1}' ORDER BY /* insert column name here, followed by ASC or DESC */");
$table = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $table[] = $row;

// at this point, each entry in the $table array is one row from 'table1'.
// shouldn't need to do array_unique or array_reverse with the modified SQL query above.

$numbers = $emails = array();
foreach ($table as $row)
{
    $number = number($row["uid2"]);
    if (strlen($number) > 9 && !in_array($numbers[$row["uid2"]], $number, true))
        $numbers[$row["uid2"]][] = $number;
    else
    {
        $email = email($row["uid2"]);
        if (!in_array($emails[$row["uid2"]], $email, true))
            $emails[$row["uid2"]][] = $email;
    }
}

// shouldn't need to do array_unique with the if-statements above

var_dump($numbers);
var_dump($emails);
```

---

**EDIT** Answering question from comments:

Based on the logic you are using, the result will probably be the same. My example above will allow this scenario for `$numbers`, while your example will not:

```
array(2)
{
    [123] => array(2)
    {
        [0] => 1234567890,    // same as $numbers[456][0]
        [1] => 9876543210
    },
    [456] => array(1)
    {
        [0] => 1234567890    // same as $numbers[123][0]
    }
}
```

But based on the way that `$number` is generated based on `$uid2`, you probably won't see any difference. What I mean is that, if `number(123)` returns `1234567890`, then `number(456)` probably will not return `1234567890`, so you probably wouldn't ever run into a scenario where you would see a difference.

---

**EDIT 2** After thinking about this some more, I'm betting that your code can be greatly simplified to this:

```
// only selecting uid2 from the table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT uid2 FROM table1 WHERE uid1 = '{$uid1}' ORDER BY /* insert column name here, followed by ASC or DESC */");

$output = array();
while (list($uid2) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $number = number($uid2);
    if (strlen($number) > 9)
        $output[$uid2]["number"] = $number;
    else
        $output[$uid2]["email"] = email($uid2);
}

var_dump($output);
```

---

**LAST EDIT** (Hopefully):

```
// only selecting uid2 from the table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT uid2 FROM table1 WHERE uid1 = '{$uid1}' ORDER BY /* insert column name here, followed by ASC or DESC */");

$numbers = $emails = array();
while (list($uid2) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $number = number($uid2);
    if (strlen($number) > 9)
        $numbers[$uid2] = $number;
    else
        $emails[$uid2] = email($uid2);
}

var_dump($numbers);
var_dump($emails);
```

Comment: this looks great! thanks. but shouldn't the in array function look like this: `!in_array($number, $numbers)`

Comment: oh awesome!! I was hoping/ thinking that this may indeed can be simplified directly from the mysql. thanks!

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row($result)` will return an array. If you use `list($uid2) = mysql_fetch_row($result)`, it gets the first value from the numeric array and assigns it to the variable `$uid2`. If you wanted the first two values from an array, you could use `list($value1, $value2) = $array;`, or if you just wanted the third value from an array, you could do `list( , , $value3) = $array;`. See the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) for further explanation.

Comment: why do my arrays look like this `{ [345678]=> array(1) { ["email"]=> string(19) "emailaddress@gmail.com" }`, how do I get it to be just: `{ [345678]=> "emailaddress@gmail.com" }`

Comment: I had both numbers and emails going into one array. See updated answer again. This will give you two separate arrays in the structure you want.

Comment: thanks! I ended up doing something similar, but with `$emails[$uid2] = $email`

Answer (score 2):

Look at this foreach:

```
        foreach($array as $uid2){
            $uid2 = $array['uid2'];
            $number = number($yfbid);
            if(strlen($number) > 9){
                $numbers[] = array('uid2' => $uid2, 'number' => $number);
            }
            else{
                $email = email($uid2);
                $yfbid[] = array('uid2' => $uid2, 'email' => $email);
            }
        }
```

You iterate all positions of array and call them $uid2. Then, in the first line you do `$uid2 = $array['uid2'];`. You loose your array position.

Maybe you wanted something like:
`$var = $uid2['uid2'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array as $uid2){
    $uid2 = $array['uid2'];
```

makes no sense. Loop over each element in $array and assign the elements to $uid2 sequentially, then kill that assigned and pull a fixed value from the same array?

As well, where is $yfbid set? From your code sample, it's undefined, and you try to convert this undefined value to a number, then check the string length of that number. Why not just `strlen($yfbid)` and let PHP handle the conversion?